# SSIS package triggering multiple instances of Powershell script

Tags: powershell, ssis

[image]SSIS package runs multiple Process tasks (5) in parallel which call / invoke the same powershell script (with different parameters being passed to it). The package works great when running locally on my machine, but when deployed to an Integration Services Catalog in SQL Server on a windows server, only 4 out of the 5 Process Tasks are calling the powershell script. Does anyone know of a setting that might be preventing the 5th Process Task from calling the Powershell script? Or is there a way I should be calling a single powershell script so that it can be processed simultaneously on a server?

Comment: What is the complete result? Does the 5th task ever get called? Does the 5th task run after one of the first four is completed? Is there any error message?

Comment: Hi there, so I checked the execution logs and the 5th task does get called / validated , there are no errors or warnings. But all I can tell in the logs is that the task gets validated and that is it. It doesn't actually do any processing.

Comment: On the task properties, what is your setting for `MaxConcurrentExecutables`?

Comment: That was it! I totally forgot about that setting. I guess when running the process locally it does not pay attention to the MaxConcurrentExecutables setting but when deployed to a server it does respect it?